# Find an equation of the sphere that passes through a point and has a center

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the sphere that passes through the point (5, 3, 1) and has center (6, 8, 10)

I already got the center down: $(x-6)^2+(y-8)^2+(z-10)^2 = r^2$ (something like this)

What do I do  when it doesn't pass through the origin, but a point?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. You do what you just did! To compute $r^2,$ just plug in your point's coordinates into the equation you've got there.

Comment: Ohhhhh I'm an idiot haha. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

So far, so good. You haven't yet used the fact that the sphere passes through $(5,3,1)$. That means that the distance between that point and the center is $r$. You can calculate that using the distance formula.